# In xfwm4, is there a way to override the application and hard code the text used in the title bar?

Tags: xfce

I use a "tabbed" scheme in Xfce/xfwm4 (tied to the B5 window manager theme).  Being able to control the tab title would make this system even more effective for me but I have yet been able to find a way to override the application from setting the title dynamically.  I suspect it may not be possible but thought it worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your windowmanager determines the 'title' of the window by looking at the WM_NAME property of the window (other props could be used as well, but WM_NAME is common). you can get that property by:

```
%> xprop WM_NAME <enter_and_click_onto_the_window>
```

by using

```
%> xprop -set WM_NAME "this is the new title" <enter_and_click_onto_the_window>
```

you can set a new title. that could do what you want. see 'man xprop' for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link to xprop.  It looks like a useful command even if it is not working for me.  Doesn't seem to have any effect but I'm guessing that even if it did it would be temporary.  For example, in Chrome, as soon as I select another tab, the tab title would become the window title (aka WM_NAME).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't currently appear to be an option for this. You can [submit a request](http://bugzilla.xfce.org/) for it though.